# Oracle + C# ошибка

Tags: c#

Подскажите почему не работает код:

```
DataTable ttt= new DataTable();
OracleConnection connection = null;
connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost:1521/aaa;UserID=USER_SESSION;Password=rrr;Connection Timeout=3;Pooling=false;");
connection.Open();
using (OracleDataAdapter _adapter = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from view_test", connection))
{
   _adapter.Fill(ttt);
}
```

При выполнении если в view например 2 столбца то работает нормально но если в view добавить ещё столбец то будет ошибка "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте вот так,правда не совсем то что Вам нужно, но может поможет

```
using (var _orCon = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    var modelList = new List<Model>();
    string _select = $"select id, name from table";
    await _orCon.OpenAsync();
    oracleConnection.Command.Connection = _orCon;
    oracleConnection.Command.CommandText = _select;
    oracleConnection.Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader _dr = oracleConnection.Command.ExecuteReader();
    while (_dr.Read())
        {
           var model = new Model
            {
                 Id = _dr["id"].ToString(),
                 Name = _dr["name"].ToString()
                 };
                 modelList.Add(model);
             }
             _orCon.Close();
             return modelList;
}
```

Comment: Я решил эту проблему проще. Запрос "select * from view_test" изменил на "select vt.x, vt.y from view_test vt " - то есть в ручную перечислил столбцы. Это решает проблему ошибки при добавлении столбца но породит ошибку при удалении столбца из view. Так и не понял почему он select * нормально переваривает только в первый раз, но если добавить в view столбец то помогает только перезагрузка C# клиента.

Comment: @SergeyZzz, есть причины полагать, что данная библиотека вполне резонно считает, что таблица не будет видоизменяться в будущем в течение работы программы, так что для ускорения дальнейшей работы просто кэширует ее текущую структуру